# Troubleshoot high cpu usage in django application

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn, cpu-usage

I try to optimise my django web application to increase max rps.
My stack includes docker+django+gunicorn+nginx

I made performance test  with yandex.tank.

When rps load is about 15 requests start to fail.

Tank writes: 
`"110 Connection timed out"`

In nginx access.log  I have:

```
 "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [27/Aug/2019:17:37:52 +0000] "GET /url HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Tank" 5.257 - [5.256]"
```

When I open htop during this test I see that all server cores are loaded at 100%

I have tried to play with proxy_read_timeout, keepalive settings but with no results.

```
upstream app {
    server django:5000;
 }

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.site.com;

    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.site.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.site.com/privkey.pem;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined_plus;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip             on;
    gzip_comp_level  2;
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_proxied     expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types       text/plain application/x-javascript text/xml text/css application/xml;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django:5000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /app/static/;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /app/media/;
    }
}
```

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  8;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format combined_plus '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]'
                         ' "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer"'
                         ' "$http_user_agent" $request_time $upstream_cache_status'
                         ' [$upstream_response_time]';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  combined_plus;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

gunicorn run command

```sh
/usr/local/bin/gunicorn config.wsgi --workers 8 --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --chdir=/app --worker-class=gevent --worker-connections=1000 --keep-alive=5
```

I can't understand problem is due to nginx and gunicorn configuration errors or in django application code.

How can I test this or profile my application to understand why gunicorn workers load cpu so much?

I have 10 cores and 64 ram on my machine.

**UPDATE:**
htop call under load showed that there are a lot of postgres "idle in transaction" processes.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I think this https://djangodeployment.readthedocs.io/en/latest/06-gunicorn.html can help you.
In my understanding, you should adjust the *workers* through trial and error.
 
Also, in this link https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1250 you will find a good conversation about it.

try: htop-tool https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/htop-command-in-linux-with-examples/